# Configuring dynamic stream input destination name for spring cloud stream aws kinesis binder

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to configure a consumer stream name via a bean instead of the property spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination= property?

We have a use case where we want to use a stream name susceptible to change and cannot hard code it.

We do not have the stream name available at runtime but is loaded and available as a property source property during bootstrap context initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a placeholder there

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=${destination.name:defaultDest}
```

Then you can pass it in as `-Ddestination.name=foo`.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the response. This will work if we had the name of the stream at application startup, however the stream is available in a property source during spring cloud bootstrap unfortunately.

Comment: This worked! Using the placeholder picked up the available property source property.